# Trigger parent API call from child in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my parent(Feed) I display a list of posts:

```
function Feed() {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await axios({
                ...
                });
    
                setPosts(result.data);
                ...
            } catch (e) {
                ...
            }
        };
        fetchPosts();
    }, []);

    return (
        ...
            {posts &&
                <div>
                    <PostCompose />                              // post creation
                    {posts.map((item, index) =>                  // map existing posts
                        <Post key={item._id} {...item} />)}      
                </div>
            }
        ...
    )
}
```

The child(PostCompose) can create a post:

```
function PostCompose() {

    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const createPost = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios({
                ...
            })
            ...
        } catch (e) {
            ...
        }
    }

    const handleTextChange = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        ...
        <textarea onChange={handleTextChange} />
        <button onClick={createPost}>Post</button>
        ...
    )
}
```

The PostCompose component makes the requests to the backend to create the new posts, but how do I trigger the Feed to refresh to pull the new list of posts?

I feel like my approach might need some work, any help would be great as I'm very new to React. Thanks.

Comment: For the record I've thought of things like creating some random state in the parent which the useEffect depends on, and then incrementing that in the child to trigger a refresh of the parent. But that really does not feel right.

Comment: You can pass down to the child component the function refreshPosts which will, as its name implies, refresh the posts data. That function of course need to update the state. Do you need a snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to take your `fetchPosts` function out of the effect callback, using the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook to memoize it. You can now invoke `fetchPosts` when the `Feed`  component mounts *and* provide it to your `PostCompose` component, as I've done here with the `afterPostCreated` prop:

```
function Feed() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);

    const fetchPosts = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios({
                // ...
            });

            setPosts(result.data);
            // ...
        } catch (e) {
            // ...
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts();
    }, [fetchPosts]);

    return (
        posts && (
            <div>
                <PostCompose afterPostCreated={fetchPosts} /> // post creation
                {posts.map(
                    (
                        item,
                        index // map existing posts
                    ) => (
                        <Post key={item._id} {...item} />
                    )
                )}
            </div>
        )
    );
}
```

Then simply invoke that callback in your `PostCompose` component, after the post was successfully created:

```
function PostCompose({ afterPostCreated }) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const createPost = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios({
                // ...
            });
            // ...

            if (afterPostCreated) {
                afterPostCreated();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // ...
        }
    };

    const handleTextChange = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <textarea onChange={handleTextChange} />
            <button onClick={createPost}>Post</button>
        </>
    );
}
```